# A weakly convergent sequence in $L_1(\Sigma, P) \subset L_1(\mathscr F, P)$ weakly converges in $L_1(\mathscr, P)$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $L_1(\Sigma, P) \subset L_1(\mathscr F, P)$, where $P$ is a probablity measure and $\Sigma$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathscr F$ generated by a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n) \in L_1(\mathscr F, P)$. If $(f_n)$ is weakly convergent in $L_1(\Sigma, P)$, Is it true that $(f_n)$ also weakly convergent in $L_1(\mathscr F, P)$?

As $\lim \int f_n g = \int f g \; \forall g \in L_{\infty}(\Sigma, P)$, what is the link between this $g$ and a $g$ in $L_{\infty}(\mathscr F, P)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and this follows from  a basic property of conditional expectations: $\int f_ng =\int f_n E(g|\Sigma)$ and $E(g|\Sigma) \in L^{\infty} (\Sigma)$ so $\int f_n g \to \int f E(g|\Sigma)=\int fg$.

Comment: Interesting. I have not been introduced with conditional expectations yet. If possible, could you please elaborate that step?

Comment: This result requires a knowledge of conditional expectations or projection operators on $L^{2}$ space. I don't know if  an elemenrtary proof is possible. Basically you have to go from a given $g \in L^{\infty}( \mathcal F)$ to a function in $L^{\infty}( \mathcal \Sigma)$. @Error404